How to generate a set of patches with a specific color or coverage
I have a variable that tells me the coverage condition of a patch. My agents move and gain energy if they are placed in certain patches (lime and orange patches). However, I must make specific patches (that are not lime or orange) change to these colors. I am telling the specific patch to change its color (it is working). But I would like to ask if there is a possibility to tell several patches in a range to change to lime and orange. I am working with a data set (raster).
ask patch  472 271  [
    set pcolor 68
    ask neighbors [
    set pcolor 68
  ] ]


What do you mean by "range"? A range of x- and y -coordinates?


How to generate a set of patches with a specific (...)?

Let's start from a clause, how this might will get used afterwards, for recolouring :
(This initial example is important for due motivation, in spite of being, the more in NetLogo parallel programming rather an anti-pattern, as explained below)
;; ...
   foreach anActualPatchSET_to_recolour [ aPATCH_to_recolour ->
        ;; perform all operations on such aPATCH_to_recolour ( modify its attributes )
           ...
        ;; done -^ loop for any next such aPATCH_to_recolour ( foreach[]-iterator drives any such AgentSet ~ PatchSET here ~ traversing )
   ]
;; ...

This is a tempting way how to implement a loop-based, serially executed ( take-one-after-another-after-... ) recipe.
Yet, we need not go this ( imperative, serial ) way at all.
Let's imagine to call all patches "at once", indeed ask them to self-identify if equipped with such attribute properties, that they become ( in their actual, local scene aware context, inside current state of evolution of our NetLogo Agent-based parallel Simulation World ) due to get re-coloured or not, and do such re-colouring "at once" :
ask patches with [ PROPERTIES-confirmed-to-re-colour ] [ PERFORM-this-patch-re-colour ]

This reads almost like my grandpa's recipe for an apple pie, yet we do not yet have the last few missing "details" - we need to describe how to execute these few "details", to indeed bake our complete "pie" in NetLogo, so :
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; a REPORTER to-report {  true | false } PROPERTIES-confirmed-to-re-colour
to-report PROPERTIES-confirmed-to-re-colour
   ifelse ( <...bool_1> { and | or } <...bool_2> ... { and | or } <...bool_i> )
          [ ;; IF 
                  report true
                  ]
          [ ;; ELSE 
                  report false
                  ]
end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; a procedure to PERFORM-this-patch-re-colour
to PERFORM-this-patch-re-colour
       set pcolor 68
    ;; set <any-PATCHES-own-ed-attribute> <a-new-value-for-this-PATCH-as-needed>
       ask neighbors [ set pcolor 68
                    ;; ...
                       ]
    ;; ...
end

